# pip connection failure: cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, pip, git-review

I run `sudo pip install git-review`, and get the following messages:

```
Downloading/unpacking git-review
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement git-review
No distributions at all found for git-review
Storing complete log in /home/sai/.pip/pip.log
```

Does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Must be a proxy connection

Comment: "none of them seem to solve my problem" Which are these? So that we do not repeat ouselves.

Answer (score 152):

I know this is an old thread, but I encountered this issue today and wanted to share my solution to the problem because I haven't seen this solution elsewhere on SO.

My environment: Python 2.7.12/2.7.14 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS in a virtualenv, pip version 1.1.

My Errors:

```
pip install nose
```

in console:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

in ~/.pip/pip.log:

```
Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

Curious for me because I had been running these same commands in a script without issue for about a year.

this fixed it:

```
pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ nose
```

(note the https)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was also having this problem on Ubuntu 12.04, which had an existing `pip 1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)` installed, which was effectively unusable.

Comment: You sir deserve a medal. I was having this problem oon my beaglebone black. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Many answers here. None of them relevant/worked-for-me except this one. Thank you!

Comment: `pip install --index-url=http://mypypi.net/simple/` throws an error `ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`

Comment: @Confounded - Thanks for pointing that out, just list the packages you want to install after the --index-url option. See the update for an example.

Comment: I am trying this way in windows. Hoped that it should have been worked. But still getting issue.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\>pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\xyz\pip\pip.log

Comment: @SureshHuse same here, on Linux, this answer seems to be outdated? `Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log`

Answer (score 61):

You need to **upgrade your pip installation** because it is still using `http` instead of `https`.

The `--index-url` (short version: `-i`) option allows you to specify an index-url in the call to pip itself, there you can use the https-variant. Then you can instruct pip to upgrade itself.

`sudo pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip`

Afterwards you should be able to use pip without the `--index-url` option.

---

I believe that the release [7.0.0 (2015-05-21)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id31) triggered this issue. The release note for that version states the following:

> **BACKWARD INCOMPATIBLE** No longer implicitly support an insecure origin
> origin, and instead require insecure origins be explicitly trusted
> with the `--trusted-host` option.

You can check your pip version with `pip --version`.

This would mean that issuing `sudo pip install --trusted-host --upgrade pip` once would also solve this issue, albeit download pip over insecure http. This might also not work at all, because it is possible that the insecure endpoint is no longer accessible on the server (I have not tested this).

Answer (score 42):

**EDIT:**

The current version of `PIP` no longer has this issue.  As of right now, version: `7.1.2` is the current version.  Here is the `PIP` link:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

**ORIGINAL FIX:**

I got this issue when trying to use `pip==1.5.4`

This is an issue related to PIP and Python's PYPI trusting SSL certificates.  If you look in the PIP log in Mac OS X at: **/Users/username/.pip/pip.log** it will give you more detail.

My workaround to get PIP back up and running after hours of trying different stuff was to go into my **site-packages** in Python whether it is in a **virtualenv** or in your normal **site-packages**, and get rid of the current PIP version.  For me I had `pip==1.5.4`

I deleted the PIP directory and the PIP egg file.  Then I ran

```
easy_install pip==1.2.1
```

This version of PIP doesn't have the SSL issue, and then I was able to go and run my normal `pip install -r requirements.txt` within my virtualenv to set up all packages that I wanted that were listed in my `requirements.txt` file.

This is also the recommended hack to get passed the issue by several people on this Google Group that I found:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/aSlPCNYcVjw

Comment: Fixed the problem for me also.

Comment: FYI, if you're reading this right now (like I did), then you should **upgrade** pip instead of downgrading it. I was very surprised to realize that I was *5 major versions behind* (we're at 6.0.8 now). Upgrading fixed the issue :)

Comment: "you should upgrade pip" 
I cannot upgrade pip for the same reason that I cant install packages; `HTTP Error 403: SSL is required`

Comment: @user5359531 Download the pip tarball from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) and do `pip install pip-x.x.x.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 13):

I added --proxy command line option to point to the proxy and it's working (pip version is 1.5.4 and python 2.7). for some reason it was not taking the shell env variables HTTPS_PROXY, HTTP_PROXY, https_proxy, http_proxy.

```
sudo pip --proxy [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port install git-review
```

Comment: are those square brackets around user required? why is symbol @ used after password?

Answer (score 11):

Check your proxy connection, I had a similar issue, then I changed my connection which wasn't proxied and boom, of it started downloading and setting up the library

Comment: How did you change your proxied connection to get it working?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I removed the proxy and change the connection to one without proxy and then once installed i changed back to work conection

Comment: Im facing the same issue and i'm pretty sure its a proxy issue. Is there a workaround other than using another connection?

Comment: I tethered to my phone to get around my company's proxy.  Nice solution.

Comment: My issue was that Fiddler was open (and I had configured Fiddler to decrypt HTTPS traffic). I closed Fiddler and it worked fine.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue with pip 1.5.6.

I just deleted the ~/.pip folder and it worked like a charm.

```
rm -r ~/.pip/
```

Comment: I cannot believe.. this worked! Thank you. Should I recreate this folder? I hope this will not affect anything else.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with `pip==1.5.6`. I had to correct my system time.

```
# date -s "2014-12-09 10:09:50"
```

Comment: Another way to correct the system time is to use ntp daemon.

Comment: worked great for me, was glad it was this simple to fix

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/ -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Ubuntu 12 helped for this question, but the answer should be read as: "Check a younger ubuntu version". By raising the ubuntu version more and more, testing this with a Dockerfile, I could fix a legacy setup, see [Docker build error "Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48819016/11154841).

Answer (score 4):

If that's not a proxy/network problem you should try to create/edit config file `.pip/pip.conf` or if you are running pip as root `/root/.pip/pip.conf`. Check and change index-url from http to **https**.

It should be like this:

```
[global] 
index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

Worked for me with Ubuntu 12 and pip 9.0.1

Answer (score 3):

it works!

sudo pip --proxy=http://202.194.64.89:8000  install elasticsearch ;
202.194.64.89:8000 is my PROXY,

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Python 3.4, in a virtual environment, running under macOS 10.10.6) I could not even upgrade `pip` itself. Help came from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769015/465139) in the form of the following one-liner:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`

(If you do not use a virtual environment, you may need `sudo python`.)

With this I managed to upgrade `pip` from Version 1.5.6 to Version 10.0.0 (quite a jump!). This version does not use TLS 1.0 or 1.1 which are not supported any more by the Python.org site(s), and can install PyPI packages nicely. No need to specify `--index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by upgrading my python, which had previously been attached to an outdated version of OpenSSL. Now it is using 1.0.1h-1 and my package will pip install.

FYI, my log and commands,  using anaconda and installing the pytest-ipynb package [1] :

```
$ conda update python
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment /Users/me/anaconda/envs/py27:
```

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    openssl:  1.0.1h-1

The following packages will be UPDATED:
    python:   2.7.5-3  --> 2.7.8-1
    readline: 6.2-1    --> 6.2-2
    sqlite:   3.7.13-1 --> 3.8.4.1-0
    tk:       8.5.13-1 --> 8.5.15-0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#############################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ] |#############################################################| 100%

$ pip install pytest-ipynb
Downloading/unpacking pytest-ipynb
  Downloading pytest-ipynb-0.1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/4f/b8gwyhg905x94twqw2pbklyw0000gn/T/pip_build_me/pytest-ipynb/setup.py) egg_info for package pytest-ipynb

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytest in /Users/me/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pytest-ipynb)
Installing collected packages: pytest-ipynb
  Running setup.py install for pytest-ipynb

Successfully installed pytest-ipynb
Cleaning up...

[1] My ticket about this issue; https://github.com/zonca/pytest-ipynb/issues/1

Comment: I'm  sorry I'm  not sure why formatting added so many blank lines?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem but that was related proxy. it was resolved by setting proxy.

```
Set http_proxy=http://myuserid:mypassword@myproxyname:myproxyport
Set https_proxy=http://myuserid:mypassword@myproxyname:myproxyport
```

This might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

If your proxy is configured correctly, then pip version 1.5.6 will handle this correctly. The bug was resolved.

You can upgrade pip with `easy_install pip==1.5.6`

Answer (score 1):

Extra answer: if you are doing this from **chroot**.

You need source of random numbers to be able to establish secure connection to pypi.

On linux, you can bind-mount host dev to chroot dev:

```
mount --bind /dev /path-to-chroot/dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error while installing pyinstaller in a proxied connection. I just connect direct Internet connection(Using my dongle) and did that again.

```
 sudo pip install pyinstaller
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing a DNS server conf in /etc/resolv.conf

make sure u can ping to:
ping pypi.python.org

if you're not getting a ping try to add a DNS server to file...something like:

nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 1):

My explanation/enquiry is for ***windows environment***.
I am pretty new to python, and this is for someone still novice than me. 
I installed the latest pip(python installer package) and downloaded 32 bit/64 bit (open source) compatible binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, and it worked.

*Steps followed to install pip, though usually pip is installed by default during python installation from* www.python.org/downloads/ 
- Download pip-7.1.0.tar.gz from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip. 
- Unzip and un-tar the above file. 
- In the pip-7.1.0 folder, run:  python setup.py install. This installed pip latest version.

*Use pip to install(any feasible operation) binary package.*
Run the pip app to do the work(install file), as below:
\python27\scripts\pip2.7.exe install file_path\file_name --proxy 
If you face, wheel(i.e egg) issue, use the compatible binary package file.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I would install django (

> pip install django

)
and it has a same problem with ssl certificate (Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ )

it's from virtualenv so DO :

FIRST:
delete your virtualenv

> deactivate
> rm -rf env

SECOND:
check have pip

> pip3 -V

if you don't have

> sudo apt-get install python3-pip

FINALLY:

install virtualenv with nosite-packages
and make your virenviroment

> sudo pip3 install virtualenv
> virtualenv  --no-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3.6
>
> . env/bin/activate

Answer (score 1):

Check ~/.pip/pip.log

It could contain the error message

`Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: 403 Client Error: [[[!!! BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]] Support for clients that do not support Server Name Indication is temporarily disabled and will be permanently deprecated soon. See https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb and https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978 [[[!!! END BREAKING CHANGE !!!]]]`

If so, the fix is to upgrade to that last version of Python 2.7.   See https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978

In my case I could do that with `add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7 && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` but YMMV may vary depending on distribution.

Comment: echo | add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7 && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but in my case I was getting the error:

```
Downloading/unpacking bencode
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://c.pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement bencode
No distributions at all found for bencode
Storing complete log in /home/andrew/.pip/pip.log
```

In my case I was able to fix the error by editing ~/.pip/pip.conf and changing `http://c.pypi.python.org/simple/` to `http://pypi.python.org/simple` and then pip worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message in `~/.pip/pip.log`

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for regulargrid
```

I fixed it by updating my `~/.pip/pip.conf`. It accidentally pointed to `cacert.pem` file that did not exist and looked like this

```
[global]
cert = /some/path/.pip/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the `easy_install pip==1.2.1` workaround but I randomly [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662073/python-django-cannot-use-imagefield-because-pillow-is-not-installed) that if you're having this bug, you probably installed a 32bit version of python.

If you install a 64bit version of it by installing it from the source and then build you virtualenv upon it, you wont have that pip bug anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I too used the chosen solution (downgrading pip) to work around this issue until I ran into another seemingly unrelated issue caused by the same underlying problem. Python's version of OpenSSL was out of date. Check your OpenSSL version:

```
python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'
```

If the version is `0.9.7`, that should verify that OpenSSL needs to be updated. If you know how to do that directly, great (but please let me know in a comment). If not, you can follow the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835554/ssl-certificate-verification-failure-in-python-on-mavericks), and reinstall python from the 64 bit/32 bit installer instead of the 32 bit only installer from python.org (I'm using python 3.4.2). I now have OpenSSL version `0.9.8`, and none of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing reinstallation of pip :

```
curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz pip-1.2.1.tar.gz
cd pip-1.2.1
python setup.py install
```

If curl doesnot work , you will have proxy issues , Please fix that it should work fine. Check after opening google.com in your browser in linux.

The try installing

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you use a firewall, make sure outbound connections to port 443 are not blocked, e.g. run:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same questions with you. When I realize it may be caused by unmatched version of numpy or pip, I uninstalled numpy and pip, then continue as this 'https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html', at last I succeed!

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\Asus>pip install matplotlib
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement matplotlib
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for matplotlib
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Asus\pip\pip.log
```

I used 'easy_install pip==1.2.1' and it worked fine.

```
C:\Users\Asus>easy_install pip==1.2.1
Searching for pip==1.2.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 1.2.1
Downloading ...
```

Then on using this command 'pip install matplotlib'

```
C:\Users\Asus>pip install matplotlib
Downloading/unpacking matplotlib
  Downloading matplotlib-2.0.0b4.tar.gz (unknown size):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running these commands in a Docker container on Windows, it may mean that your docker machine's network connection is stale and needs to be rebuilt. To fix it, run these commands:

```
docker-machine stop
docker-machine start
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO @%i
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm now getting this in `$HOME/.pip/pip.log`:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: HTTP Error 403: TLSv1.2+ is required
```

I don't have a straightforward solution for this, but I'm mentioning it as something to watch out for before you waste time on trying some of the other solutions here.

- I'm obviously already using a https URL
- There is no proxy or firewall issue
- Using `trusted-host` didn't change anything (dunno where I picked this up)

For what it's worth my `openssl` is too old to even have `ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION` so maybe that's really the explanation here.

In the end, wiping my virtual environment and recreating it with `virtualenv --setuptools env` seems to have fixed at least the major blockers.

This is on a really old Debian box, Python 2.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the system `virtualenv` version.

When I created an env with python3 venv everything worked. But when I used virtualenv (by default with python2.7) to create an env I receive those error messages.

In the `virtualenv` created the pip version was `1.5.6`, but my system pip version was `10.0.1`

Then I ran (outside any env):

`pip install virtualenv --upgrade`

It upgraded `virtualenv` to version `16.0.0` and now my `pip install` in the envs created with `virtualenv` and `python2.7` work flawlessly. Also, the `pip` version inside the env is now `10.0.1`.

Before upgrade:

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost all answers and nothing fix my error, so I just reinstall python (in my case I have version 2.7.9 and I install 2.7.15) and the error finally fixed.
No need to uninstall python first, the installer do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this below command:

> > > python -m pip install --trusted-host https://pypi.python.org deepdiff

it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions from Daniel F and mattdedek very helpful: use an https URL, and upgrade pip in order to make that the default. But that still didn't fix the problem for me. I had this error, under Mac OS X / Python 3.4:

```
$ pip3 install Flask
Downloading/unpacking Flask
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Flask
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Flask
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/huttarl/.pip/pip.log
```

and pip.log basically showed the same thing:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req) 
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for Flask
```

With help from a friend, I learned that **upgrading from Python 3.4 to 3.8** fixed the problem. Apparently this is because one of the newer versions of Python 3 included **updated certificates**:

> Certificate verification and OpenSSL
>
> This package includes its own private copy of OpenSSL 1.1.1.   The
>   trust certificates in system and user keychains managed by the
>   Keychain Access application and the security command line utility are
>   not used as defaults by the Python ssl module.  A sample command
>   script is included in /Applications/Python 3.8 to install a curated
>   bundle of default root certificates from the third-party certifi
>   package (https://pypi.org/project/certifi/).  Double-click on Install
>   Certificates to run it.
>
> The bundled pip has its own default certificate store for verifying
>   download connections.

After this upgrade, and running `Install Certificates.command`, the `pip3 install Flask` runs successfully.

You may have already upgraded to Python 3.6+ in Mac OS, and just overlooked this certificate installation command. In that case, browse to Applications/Python 3.x and double-click `Install Certificates.command`. (See [Mac OSX python ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify/42098127#42098127))

Answer (score 0):

Late 2022 answer after working on a legacy system:

Check a younger ubuntu version. By raising the ubuntu version more and more, testing this with a Dockerfile, I could fix a legacy setup by taking Ubuntu 18, see [Docker build error "Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74563036/11154841).

Answer (score -1):

For my case, I fix it by:

I copied `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` and `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` from Anaconda3\Library\bin to \Anaconda3\DLLs.

Comment: How does this relate to a connection failure in `pip`?

Comment: I don't know the reason either, but it worked for me. @snakecharmerb