# How can I install a specific version of pip via easy-install? - Mac OS Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install

I am constantly getting the

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

whenever I try to pip install anything with the most recent pip version.

I read on some other questions that pip was having SSL related issues in its latest version and recommended to install pip 1.2.1.

How do I install a specific version of pip via easy_install for example?

Answer (score 32):

You should be able to install pip with pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip==1.2.1
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I still get the same error as mentioned in the question =\. Is there a way to install pip via a different package manager to circumvent the SSL error?

Comment: For me, pip 1.5.5 works fine on mavericks, so I'm not sure your issue is caused by an issue with 1.5.5. However, did you look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl  ? You can try following the steps he recommends.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your context, you can uninstall as above and then run:

```
sudo easy_install pip==1.2.1
```

No more pesky SSL errors.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall any previous installation of `pip`. Considering you are using system wide installation,

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

and also,

```
pip uninstall pip
```

Now,

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip==<specific version>
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

It's preferred to use `virtual environment` though.

Comment: I am on Mavericks, and although this works on my ubuntu vm, it still doesn't solve my issue: which is to install pip 1.2.1 on Mac OS X Mavericks. 

Of course, I am assuming that apt-get is a Linux only package manager. Thanks though :)

Comment: you can use `brew` in mac.