# Problems when installing gensim on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gensim

I have been trying to install `gensim` using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

I got the following error messages:

```
Downloading/unpacking gensim
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement gensim
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for gensim
Storing debug log for failure in /home/users/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the version of Ubuntu, which is installed on Windows through VmWare

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: I do not get the same error - the install works for me (on OS X Mavericks, admittedly). Have you tried looking at the log? Could you provide more details about your setup?

Comment: I was just able to successfully install gensim on Ubuntu 12.04.5, what version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi,  I updated the setup information on the above. Which kind of log information I should take a look at. Please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're having a problem with pip -- the following post should fix your problem.  I'm running 14.04 and the version of pip is 1.5.4, which is what Aron was running (and probably what you have).

His fix was to remove pip and install the current version using

```
easy_install pip==1.2.1
```

I would also recommend making sure all of your packages are up to date -- I haven't had this problem and as I said, am running the same version you are.

His answer in detail is:

> [pip connection failure: cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl)

Comment: why the downvote?  Comments would be helpful.....especially when no one else has anything to suggest.