# How to install Django in virtualenv python 2.7

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

please tell me some way to install Django in ubuntu in virtualenv without using pip for python 2.7 
I am using a proxy connection. I have tried the steps shown in other answers for exporting proxy for pip .

when I try `pip install Django==1.6.2` it shows error

```
Downloading/unpacking Django
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Django
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for Django
Storing debug log for failure in /home/shivam/.pip/pip.log
```

Also , I am unable to install anything using pip.

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to install django 1.6.x instead of a newer version?

Comment: may be a temporary network problem or problem with pypi site, but pretty sure this should be lowercase too: `pip install django==1.6.2`

Comment: Which version of pip are you using? What does logs said (`/home/shivam/.pip/pip.log`)?

Comment: pip version is 1.5.4.  what do you mean by "What does logs said (/home/shivam/.pip/pip.log)?"i have also tried installin other versions of Django but the same error appears.

Comment: Pasting your debug log file could help too ;)

Comment: I use Debian 8 and it works. I could not reproduce the error. What is your pip version? What is your virtualenv version? What is in the log?

Answer (score 1):

If your using pip 1.5.4, you should read this topic : [pip connection failure: cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl). So, you should upgrade pip in your virtualenv: `pip install --upgrade pip` (see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip).

Comment: I get this error while upgrading pip                                                               Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/                        
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /home/shivam/.pip/pip.log

Comment: Did you check your log file (`/home/shivam/.pip/pip.log`)?
Maybe you have a proxy, like said in the other post, haven't you?

Comment: ya i have a proxy which was the cause of it ,  finally the issue is solved