# open cv : A series of OpenCV convenience functions.s imutils and cvuitls not installing

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, pip, ubuntu-14.04

i tried with this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cvutils/0.1

i tried many ways but I'm not getting proper way to install these things. my pip version is 1.5.4 .  `pip install imutils and cvutils` the logon terminal is as follows: [I'm getting this error which is shown by red color for every installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08mcN.png)

```
sachin_hd_user@sachin:~$ pip install cvutils
Downloading/unpacking cvutils
  Downloading cvutils-0.2.4.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_sachin_hd_user/cvutils/setup.py) egg_info for package cvutils

    warning: no files found matching 'data'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7 (from cvutils)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->cvutils)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->cvutils)
Downloading/unpacking tornado (from matplotlib->cvutils)
  Downloading tornado-4.3.tar.gz (450kB): 450kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_sachin_hd_user/tornado/setup.py) egg_info for package tornado

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
    warning: no files found matching 'tornado/test/README'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing>=1.5.6 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->cvutils)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from matplotlib->cvutils)
Downloading/unpacking backports.ssl-match-hostname (from tornado->matplotlib->cvutils)
  Downloading backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_sachin_hd_user/backports.ssl-match-hostname/setup.py) egg_info for package backports.ssl-match-hostname

Downloading/unpacking singledispatch (from tornado->matplotlib->cvutils)
  Downloading singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking certifi (from tornado->matplotlib->cvutils)
  Downloading certifi-2016.2.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (366kB): 366kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking backports-abc>=0.4 (from tornado->matplotlib->cvutils)
  Downloading backports_abc-0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from singledispatch->tornado->matplotlib->cvutils)
Installing collected packages: cvutils, tornado, backports.ssl-match-hostname, singledispatch, certifi, backports-abc
  Running setup.py install for cvutils
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/cvutils-resize from 644 to 755
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/cvutils-crop from 644 to 755
    error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cvutils': Permission denied
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_sachin_hd_user/cvutils/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-aSeyDC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cvutils

copying cvutils/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cvutils

copying cvutils/cvimgproc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cvutils

copying cvutils/cvhighgui.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cvutils

copying cvutils/cvos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cvutils

running build_scripts

creating build/scripts-2.7

copying and adjusting bin/cvutils-resize -> build/scripts-2.7

copying and adjusting bin/cvutils-crop -> build/scripts-2.7

changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/cvutils-resize from 644 to 755

changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/cvutils-crop from 644 to 755

running install_lib

creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cvutils

error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cvutils': Permission denied

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_sachin_hd_user/cvutils/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-aSeyDC-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_sach[enter image description here][1]in_hd_user/cvutils
Storing debug log for failure in /home/sachin_hd_user/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have root permission to install python packages system wide.

Use `sudo pip install cvutils` or install it in a virtualenv.

Comment: i already tried this one :

sachin_hd_user@sachin:~$ sudo pip install cvutils
[sudo] password for sachin_hd_user: 
Downloading/unpacking cvutils
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cvutils
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for cvutils
Storing debug log for failure in /home/sachin_hd_user/.pip/pip.log

Comment: That is a different issue. Looks like an old version of pip. It might be fixed by running `sudo pip install pip --upgrade` first. If that doesn't work, there's some info here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl