# Error when installing rpy2 module in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-14.04, rpy2

I used the command:

```
 sudo pip install rpy2
```

and I got the following error:

```
 Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
 Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement rpy2
 Cleaning up...
 No distributions at all found for rpy2
 Storing debug log for failure in /home/elena/.pip/pip.log
```

How could I fix the problem? Any suggestion?

Comment: What`s the version of pip? Probably, this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21294997/1423473

Comment: @erthalion version 8.1.1

Comment: Please paste the debug log from the error message as part of the question. I suspect you're behind a proxy and need to set the appropriate variables in the environment (`http_proxy` and `https_proxy`)

Does `curl https://pypi.python.org/simple/rpy2/` work for you from the same environment?

Comment: @ffledgling thanks for your suggestion, the problem rounded towards the proxy

Comment: @ElenaPhys if you found a solution, please write it down as an answer so that other users that run into the same problem know the fix.

Comment: @ffledgling for sure: i used the git-repository of  asmeurer [link](https://github.com/asmeurer) via the command  `conda install -c asmeurer rpy2`