# Docker build error "Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/"

Tags: git, docker, pip, dockerfile

I am building a dockerfile with the `docker build .` command. While building, I am experiencing the following error:

```
Downloading/unpacking requests
   Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement requests
   No distributions at all found for requests
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM jonasbonno/rpi-grovepi
RUN pip install requests
RUN git clone https://github.com/keyban/fogservice.git #update
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["fogservice/service.py"]
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I am not. I can open the url normally in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pip problem, not a docker problem, you need to add `pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip` to your docker file:

```
FROM jonasbonno/rpi-grovepi
RUN pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip
RUN hash -r
RUN pip install requests
RUN git clone https://github.com/keyban/fogservice.git #update
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["fogservice/service.py"]
```

You can find the solution here: [pip connection failure: cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl)

Comment: There is a typo in your first code line: missing the 'p' in _p_ip. Since it is a single char change, I cannot edit it myself.

Comment: In Python 2.7, when trying to update in the Dockerfile or in the container, you get `Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log`. See also the two comments at the end of [pip connection failure: cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963820/11154841)

Comment: Found it out and put it in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74563036/11154841), you need to take a younger base image in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

##### Legacy problem

In Python 2.7, a pip installer of *Pylons* threw the same error. I then read somewhere that upgrading *pip* could help, and doing so in the bash of the container, you get the same error again, now for *pip* itself:

```bash
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

And when you try upgrading pip in the Dockerfile, you get the same output, but at the end:

```bash
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple/ --upgrade pip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

See also the two comments at the end of [pip connection failure: cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963820/11154841)

The error is thrown only from within your container / when building the image, while in your workspace, you can install the upgrade or the packages. The container's pip does not have the rights to download from the internet since the [TLS security changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49901622/11154841).

##### Answer 1: load from your own *pip* server

I saw a fix in a legacy docker setup, likely for the same reason as in the question. This is not for sure, though, I have not done it myself:

Download the *pip* installers of the packages you need in your workspace, then upload these *pip* installers to a local server with your own certificate, and then add that server website with your own setup to a python `setup.py` file by means of `from setuptools import setup, find_packages`, then calling the built-in `setup(...)` function, to *pip install* the needed packages.

In short: Do not upgrade the *pip* installer for this, instead, just have the needed tarballs on your own server to get them without TLS problems, and take the `setuptools` module in a python file for this.

##### Answer 2: take a younger ubuntu base image in the Dockerfile (recommended)

In a legacy project, for example written in Python 2, try changing the base image, and perhaps even the Python version. I changed the line from `FROM ubuntu:14.04` to `15.04`, `16.04`, and then `18.04`. Then I tried `pip install Pylons` and all of the other needed packages in the bash of the container, but that only worked after

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

(*In my project, I could not get the docker containers to run without this, although I vaguely remember that you should not need to upgrade pip if you take the right image from the start; not sure about this, though, perhaps that was only aiming at updated, not upgrade.*)

When all of the versions were clear and the app worked, I added the pip installations to a requirements file that gets loaded in the Dockerfile.