# Why does PyCharm say "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: ..." whenever I try to install any library in the project interpreter?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, package

I installed Python 3.9.2 and PyCharm 2020-3.3 and since I did this, I am unable to install Python packages in the project interpreter. I can't even upgrade my pip both in CMD, and the PyCharm terminal.

Whenever I try to install any library in the interpreter, it shows error installing package and when I try to install using the terminal, it shows

> "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: ..."

I need a step-by-step approach in resolving this issue.

Do not direct me to any link, let me know what you used in resolving your case if you've ever experienced this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21294997) seems to have a number of solutions. If those answers don't solve the problem they will probably help you narrow down the causes. See if one of the answers works for you, if not edit the question to add more specific information that may be relevant towards a solution.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: sometimes PyPi has problem with its servers but it can be also problem with your access to internet.

Comment: I usually experience this whenever I download a newer version of pycharm as from version 2020.1 upward. It has to do with the pip. Pip version 21 doesn't work in some systems. I've not really tried to look into how to fix it. Using Pycharm 2019.3.5 downwards have no issue with the pip.