# Why am I Unable to install flask (PIP error)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-14.04

I am Unable to install Flask or nearly any other modules.
My OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32bit).
Ubuntu Comes with pre installed Python2 and Python3.
As I had work with flask, I tried to install it with the following command:

```
pip3 install flask
```

and this was the output in the terminal:

```
root@Ashu-linx:/var/www# pip3 install flask
Downloading/unpacking flask
Downloading Flask-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (94kB): 94kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking itsdangerous>=2.0 (from flask)
Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking Jinja2>=3.0 (from flask)
Downloading Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (133kB): 133kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug>=2.0 (from flask)
Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (288kB): 288kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking click>=7.1.2 (from flask)
Downloading click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97kB): 97kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2482, in _dep_map
return self.__dep_map
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2344, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, 
bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
req_to_install.extras):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2291, in requires
dm = self._dep_map
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2484, in _dep_map
self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2517, in 
_compute_dependencies
common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2514, in reqs_for_extra
if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-3.3-py2.py3-none- 
any.whl/_markerlib/markers.py", line 113, in marker_fn
return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Then I checked My PIP version with the help of:

```
pip3 --version
```

And The Output Was:

```
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Then I thought of updating it first:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then It gave me the following error:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip in 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Then I searched for this error online and found a [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294997/pip-connection-failure-cannot-fetch-index-base-url-http-pypi-python-org-simpl)
And found the following command:

```
pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask
```

Then I ran the same command but a warning came:

```
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

Can someone tell me what should I do now?
I have read the Flask Installation Guide but It didn't help me.

Comment: When you ran `pip install --upgrade pip` you were running pip for python 2.7 and not pip3.

Comment: I think the command may be missing a space: `pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/  flask`

Answer (score 0):

```
File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined
```

This means that version of pip (in Python 3.4) that you used is too old for the newer versions of the module.
The solution is to upgrade pip, but you ended up upgrading the Python 2 pip instead.

The best way to make sure you are targeting the right pip is to run it like this:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Or,

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

In Windows,

```
py -3.4 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by Joe:

> I think the command may be missing a space: `pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/  flask`

That is correct for the command line, this resolves the problem for me, as it is not about pip version.

In fact, I used the following on Jessie (aka Debian 8):

pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple  flask==0.10.1

Since I am trying to install Flask on Jessie 8, and python 2.7.

But, that in itself is likely not the problem, since I get a problem with missing setup file regardless of using:

pip install Flask==0.10.1

pip install --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple  flask==0.10.1

Both draw down the same package.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.